# How to get AWS Account ID by Canonical ID by programming?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to check the permissions on the S3 bucket on other accounts than the owner of the bucket account. The AWS console is asking me for the "Canonical ID" for the user. For example, I have a "Canonical ID" how do I determine this account belongs to "AWS Account ID" (A 12-digit number, such as 123456789012). I'm working on Java SDK and AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Canonical user ID is an obfuscated form of the AWS account ID. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html)]